# Check if key exists in eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a helper function that checks if a specific key exists inside an eloquent model to generate a dynamic query that only checks for the correct keys.

I have made to helper functions like such:

```
if(!function_exists('entityHasKey')){
    function entityHasKey(Model $eloquentModel, string $key): bool
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $eloquentModel->getAttributes());
    }
}

if(!function_exists('hasEntityKeys')){
    /**
     * @param string $eloquentModel
     * @param string[] $keys
     * @return bool
     */
    function entityHasKeys(string $eloquentModel, array $keys): bool
    {
        $hasKey = false;

        foreach($keys as $key){
            if(entityHasKey($eloquentModel, $key)){
                $hasKey = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $hasKey;
    }
}
```

In my head, the logic makes good sense, but the issue is now that I can't pass the attributes from the class (without having an instance). My best guess would be the use the static class instance, but that only gets me the name.

What is the best approach to check if a key exists on an eloquent model (without an instance necessarily)

*usage example*

```php
(*other conditions * and entityHasKeys(MyCoolModel::class, $filters['columns']))
```

Comment: You'd probably need to convert the Model to an Array, then check `array_key_exists`, but with or without an instance, that might not work... If you do `(new Model())->toArray()`, you get an empty array, since a Model's attributes (keys) aren't populated until it's pulled from the DB. What's the specific use case here, and is there any reason you can't just check `$model->property`?

Comment: You can't do that with Eloquent because the models are constructed from a query result, you don't know what columns exists on a table until you get a row from the actual table. You can use doctrine's [listTableColumns](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html#listtablecolumns) to get a list of columns of a table and you can get the table name from the Eloquent model via e.g. `(new $eloquentModel)->getTable()`. If you don't want to use doctrine then you can call something like `DESCRIBE TABLE` manually

Comment: The use case I tried to explain as that I have an array of keys and want to check if those keys exist inside the model. Maybe this can be done with form requests in a better way??

Comment: Are the values that you're looking for essentially just the column names of the table, or do you use any dynamic attributes that are not present in the table? If so, my answer might help you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a _specific_ use case; which keys, which model, and why you can't just check the model at runtime, like `if($model->whatever) { // Do something since this key exists }`, or `array_diff($expectedKeys, $model->toArray())`, etc. I still don't know what exactly you're trying to do, sorry 

Answer (score 4):

The `Schema` facade has a method called [`getColumnListing()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.html#method_getColumnListing) which takes the table name as a parameter. If you want to get all the columns that are present in the table (which are essentially the possible attributes) you can do something like this.

You may use the `app()` helper to get the table name without an instance of the model.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$attributes = Schema::getColumnListing(
    app(\App\Models\User::class)->getTable()
);
```

You can then create a function that accepts an attribute name as a string or multiple attributes in an array that should be checked for, in combination with the model name as a string (e.g. `User`).

```php
function modelHasAttributes(string $model, string|array $attributes): bool
{
    $attributes = is_array($attributes) ? $attributes : [$attributes];

    $modelAttributes = Schema::getColumnListing(
        app("\App\Models\\$model")->getTable()
    );

    return count(array_intersect($attributes, $modelAttributes)) === count($attributes);
}
```

This will yield you the following results (tested with default `User` model).

```php
modelHasAttributes('User', 'name');    // true
modelHasAttributes('User', 'nope');    // false

modelHasAttributes('User', ['id', 'name']);    // true
modelHasAttributes('User', ['id', 'nope']);    // false
```

Comment: Great answer! One improvement you could make though, `modelHasAttributes(string $model, string | array $attributes)`, then `$attributes = is_array($attributes) ? $attributes : [$attributes];`, then use the `array_intersect` method to check (even for a single one). Laravel uses similar logic for a number of methods, and makes it so you don't need to use `modelHasAttribute` for one vs `modelHasAttributes` for multiple, it would simply be `modelHasAttributes('user', 'name')` or `modelHasAttributes('user', ['name', 'other'])` 